# woocommerce страница атрибутов отображается как блог

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

по инструкции на оф сайте woocommerce 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/using-custom-attributes-in-menus/
добавила код в functions.php
и добавила файл taxonomy-pa_materials. php в мойшаблон/woocommerce папку

в меню появились свойства (attributes)
а вот на самой странице свойства - отображаются товары с этим свойством(они так и раньше отображались), но отображаются в виде блога - и чтобы я не делала с файлами в папке woocommerce - это никак не отображается на шаблоне этой страницы - а хочется чтобы в ней товары отображались также как и на странице метки или категории товаров

гугл поиск вообще не помог, плагины какие то устанавливала тоже не помогло

WordPress 3.8.23, Woo 2.0.14

Comment: какая задача? Что нужно сделать?

Comment: [Ссылка](https://www.pixelrush.com.au/blog/woocommerce-custom-attributes-in-menus/)

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашла сама, вдруг кому пригодится)
нужно внимательно читать текст статьи на сайте поддержки woo оказывается)

в общем этот файл taxonomy-pa_materials. php нужно было кидать не в папку woocomerce в теме, а в корень темы - и все заработало сразу